# HP ML350 Replacing a Drive Marked as Predicted to Fail

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array

We have an ML350P Gen8 server with an HP Smart Array P420i.

Three 300GB drives are combined in RAID5. Of these, one drive is showing a flashing amber light (predictive failure).

The cache for the P420i has been disabled because the backup power source attached to the cache module has failed to charge. (I am looking to fix this, but would like to sort out the drive first).

My question is: can I just press the hot-swap button, pull the drive that is predicted for failure and replace it and the rebuild will start automatically? Or do I need to take additional actions as the drive has not yet failed?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar situation with the same server model. Just curious on what you ended up doing on your server, did you just push the hot-swap button on predictive failure? Were you able to put the new drive in and it rebuilt ok?